# What is the division of inheritance in this case?

Tags: inheritance

My father passed away back in 2001, may Allah bless his soul and Jennah ferdos.

His parents, my grandparents passed away long before.  We have my mother and 2 males (myself incuded) and 2 females as his children.  How should the inheritance been divided according to Allah (swt) who is the provider and sustainer of everything?

Comment: [This is not a fatwa site.](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: For clearing that we need more information: Did your father have siblings etc. there are many people involved in inheritance matters!

Comment: No his siblings were all older and passes away before.

Comment: @Medi1Saif Would a sibling get inheritance in the presence of sons?

Comment: @Uma honestly it has been some 20-25 years since i studied inheritance at school.At the time i was very fit and could solve difficult issues, but since i've never dealt with it again i have no clue.

Comment: @Medi1Saif I was curious if there is a difference on this between the schools. In an inheritance I was involved in, the sons blocked the siblings. The only question asked was if the parents of the deceased were alive and whether there are any other wives\children.

Comment: @G.Bach  A fatwa is an interpretive judgement by an Islamic scholar on matters that are not clearly defined in Quran and hadith.  This is not the case with inheritance.  There are clear formulas to be followed.  I pretty much know what the solution is but I wanted 3rd party verification as we have a dispute with siblings who are not knowledgeable in this area.  I have checked the help center and I don't see how my question is off-topic.  It is not a fatwa question and other viewers would benefit.  Please either specify why it is off-topic or re-open the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your father has no other spouses or children, and his parents died before him, and any debts and wills have been settled.

Your mother gets 1/8th since she has children:

> [Quran 4:12](https://quran.com/4/12) And for the wives is one fourth if you leave no child.
>   But if you leave a child, then for them is an eighth of what you
>   leave, after any bequest you [may have] made or debt.

The presence of a son among children blocks farther relatives. The remainder is divided among the children so that a son gets twice the share of a daughter.

> [Quran 4:11](https://quran.com/4/11) Allah instructs you concerning your children: for the
>   male, what is equal to the share of two females.

So, your mother would get 12.5% of the total, you and your brother would get 29.16% each and the sisters would get 14.58% each to sum to a total of 100%.